# Loop for snmpwalk in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have an issue in my output using snmpwalk so i'm trying in this script:

```
var=`snmpwalk -v2c -c private ${ip} .1.1.1.6`
echo "${hostname}=>${var}"
```

to have this output:

```
R1=>Gauge32: 240
R1=>Gauge32: 293
R1=>Gauge32: 255
R1=>Gauge32: 25
```

but actually i have this output :

```
R1=>Gauge32: 240
Gauge32: 293
Gauge32: 255
Gauge32: 25
```

so how can i have the output that i need in bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working how you want as you are printing hostname before all the lines stored in the string `$var`. instead of looping and printing hostname before each line.

Here is one way to loop through them using a pipe and awk

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c private ${ip} .1.1.1.6 | awk -vHost="${hostname}" '{print Host"=>"$0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the output as a whole (with the embedded newline characters) in a *scalar* variable, you could (I didn't say you *should*) store lines in an array variable.

With `ksh93`, `mksh`, `bash`, `zsh` in `sh` emulation:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline
set -f
var=($(snmpwalk -v2c -c private "$ip" .1.1.1.6))
```

And then use `printf` like:

```
printf "$hostname=>%s\n" "${var[@]}"
```

That assumes however that `$hostname` doesn't contain percent or backslash characters.

`rc` and `zsh` make it easier:

- `rc`:

  ```
  var = (``('
  '){snmpwalk -v2c -c private $ip .1.1.1.6})
  printf %s\n $hostname'=>'^$var
  ```
- `zsh`:

  ```
  var=(${(f)"$(snmpwalk -v2c -c private $ip .1.1.1.6)"})
  printf '%s\n' $hostname'=>'$^var
  ```

(note that all those solutions ignore empty lines)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to assign the whole output of the command to a variable and then do the formatting. But if you want to do so you can use `printf` to do the formatting. The key is to expand `hostname` inside the format string, so that only the list of the *type-value* pairs in `var` will be affected by the format specifiers (`%s` and `%d` in this case), and `printf` guarantees the reuse of the format specifiers for every data pair:

```
var=`snmpwalk -v2c -c private ${ip} .1.1.1.6`
printf "${hostname}=>%s %d\n" ${var}
```

(Note: There's no quotes around `${var}` is this case.)